# Primitive types in .net

Tags: c#, .net, int, clr, primitive-types

In .net, AIUI `int` is just syntactic sugar for `System.Int32`, which is a `struct`.

```
csharp> typeof(System.Int32).IsPrimitive 
true
csharp> typeof(System.Int32).Equals(typeof(int))
true
```

I see in the source:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int32.cs
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs

That `System.Int32` is just defined with reference to a member `m_value` that is itself an `int` - how does that work? Surely we're defining `int` with reference to itself? So how do we avoid circular definition then?

Comment: Well, i'd assume that m_value must reference this, but i can't find any evidence in code

Comment: No, in `C#`, `int` is syntactic sugar for `System.Int32`. In VB.Net, `Integer` is syntactic sugar for `System.Int32`.

Comment: Did´nt he say the same?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - if that's a response to my comment, I'm trying to point out that .net != c#.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an excellent explanation in Dixin's blog article [Understanding .NET Primitive Types](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-net-primitive-types).

The answer can be found in the generated IL. His following question is actually the answer to your question:

> So what is the relationship among int32 (IL), int (C#) and System.Int32 (C#)?

In the IL can be found that the `int` inside the `struct` is:

```
.field assembly int32 m_value
```

So that `int32` actually exists outside .NET and is the actual representation of the .NET `int` in assembly.

Comment: This essentially seems to be correct. I would add -
- Such CLR primitive types seem to be enumerated in section II.7.1 Types and interestingly include string (why isn't that a wrapper around `char[]`?)[the cli spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)
- mcs seems to always give you an `int32` when you ask for an int or a System.Int32. Whenever you need to invoke a method on it it uses the CIL `constrained.` prefix to treat it as an Int32.
- That I cannot say `public enum Status : Int32 {}` isn't really a consequence of Int32 not being primitive?

Comment: Another relevant section of the CLR spec is I.8.2.2 which relates the mscorlib types to CLR primitives