# Is Primitive types Exist in C#?

Tags: c#

**Update 2**

As `int a` in primitive perspective we simply can not call or access methods, but in c# declaration of type has methods like `ToString()` also numbers has methods available, example: `0.ToString()`

I Wanted to know what exactly an `int a` a primitive or an object.

Also if `int a` or `bool a` is an object, there is "No primitive concept" in C# right?

---

P.s. My "low-quality" question well answered by Eric, This question updated for further.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009327/primitive-types-in-net https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Those primitive types aren't defined in C# language, but in the .NET framework C# uses. There is a method which allows you to determine if a type is primitive: `Type.isPrimitive`

Comment: I hate to be that guy but this is a combo dupe\ poor quality question. Read this before asking questions on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @w.b `Int32 a = new Int32()` Compiles fine for me. I will keep look into Struct more.

Comment: I knew there is gonna be lots of thumbs down. but i want to sacrifices it for a answer. I really want to know this.

Comment: @Terrance Just what i looked for. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please ask only one question per question.

> Is Int32 a = new Int32() equal to int a ?

No. It is the equivalent of `int a = 0;`

> If not: How its possible to write a.ToString() ?

Ints have a method called ToString. You called it.

> Do we have primitive types in C#?

The C# specification uses the word "primitive" once, and it is not at all clear what it means in the context of the specification. The concept of "primitive type" is not an important one in the study of C#.

> According to this Question Int32 and int are pretty much the same thing. Shorthand preferred for Readability and Style.

Correct.

> So: According to java, Primitive types are the most basic data types available.

Java is not C#.

Comment: When i declare `a` as `int a` i still have this `ToString()` method available. How it is possible. int is not a class right?

Comment: @PJ3: Why would it not be possible?  The int type has a method called ToString. You can call that method.  Why would you not be able to call a method on a type that has that method?

Comment: @PJ3: Who says that you have to be a class to call a method?  You can call a method on a struct, a class, an interface, a delegate, an enum or a type parameter.

Comment: wow. the whole oop consepts just flush away from my brain. i am sorry i came from java. i just have one question. can i declare custom type? ok you answered. yes. thank you very much.

Comment: @PJ3: Java is not C#. Yes, in C# you can declare your own struct types, if that is what you are asking. That feature is not (yet) in Java.

Comment: @PJ3: I suspect that your issue is that Java makes a very strong distinction between the "boxed" and "unboxed" form of int, double, bool, and so on. C# does not.  There are situations in which a value type must be treated as a reference type; in those cases the boxing operation happens automatically.  Note that calling ToString does not box; there is a version of ToString defined on int that takes a ref int as "this", rather than an object as "this".